# A way to list the default namespace and sub-namespaces of all projects in a solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

We are very close to have a fully polished application and now, we find occasional old namespaces or sometimes, no namespaces in many projects. There are around 350 projects. Is there a way have all the namespaces listed from a solution?

I'd start with the Default namespace first:

[image]

These are quite messed up in different projects but the code files under are Ok.

Answer (score 1):

View --> Object Browser will display a window with a treeview on the left letting you expand each project and see the namespaces it contains.  That's probably the most efficient way of manually reviewing things.  Note it won't show you the default namespace in each csproj but will show you all of the namespaces that are actually used.  To find all the default namespaces, crack open a csproj file in notepad to see how the default namespace is defined then do a "find in files" to look for that section in each of the other csproj files.

Comment: Already doing that and not enjoying a bit. I remember an extension printed this information but it was not a free extension. And the generated output could not be copied or saved/exported.